# Lower bound for the sum of divisor function

Tags: number-theory

Let $\sigma$ be the *sum-of-divisors* function defined by 
$$
\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d.
$$
Is there an explicit lower bound for $\sigma(n)/n$ in the style of the lower bound 
$$
\phi(n) > \dfrac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{3}{\log \log n}}
$$
for $n > 2$, where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant? I'm aware that the inequality 
$$
\dfrac{6}{\pi^2} < \dfrac{\phi(n) \sigma(n)}{n^2} < 1,
$$
for $n > 1$, is known. But can we get a better lower bound than $\sigma(n)/n > 6n/\pi^2\phi(n)$?

Comment: Interesting upper bounds, yes. Lower bounds, no. Whenever $n$ is prime, $$ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}.  $$

Comment: upper bounds, short version at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808168/how-to-prove-dn2n-log-log-n/808178#808178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do better if you want a lower bound that holds for *all* $n$.  If you consider the sequence of integers which are products of the consecutive primes, i.e. $$2, \;2\cdot3, \;2\cdot3\cdot5, \;2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7,\,\dots$$
you can see that your bound is sharp.

For better bounds on subsets of the positive integers, you might want to look at the following [this paper by Medryk](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2005-18-3/10/10.pdf).

Comment: I guess this is what he wanted. Meanwhile, take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323144/eulers-phi-function-worst-case/323229#323229 as the Nicolas criterion deserves to be better known.

Comment: @WillJagy - Thanks!  That is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever n is prime, Sigma(n)=n+1

Whenever n>1 is composite Sigma (n)> n+ (n)^0.5

The proof is found at:  http://www.americanriver.com/mathematics/elementary_number_theory.html      under chaper 6.1 " the functions tau and sigma" :  task 10.c)