# Factors of $2n^2 \leq n$?

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

How many factors of $2n^2$ are less than or equal to $n$?
I know that the number of factors of $n^2$ less than $n$ is half the number of factors of $n^2$ (each factor $< n$ corresponds with one greater than $n$), but $2n^2$ is a whole different case, it seems. Is there any way to find an expression for this? And if not, is there an algorithm for it? I have looked into both combinatorics and prime factorization, but have arrived at dead-ends.

Comment: The factors of $2n^2$ are $1, 2, n, 2n, n^2, $ and $2n^2$.

Comment: No, those are the only "sure" factors that we know. For example, 2*15^2 = 450 is also divisible by 5, 18, and 25, to name a few.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  I think OP is considering the case where $n$ is composite.  For example, $450=2\cdot 15^2$ has $18$ factors, $8$ of which are less than or equal to $15$.

Comment: @Han: there isn't an easy way to answer this without knowing the prime factorization of $n$. Unlike the $n^2$ case there isn't a neat trick.

Comment: I do know the prime factorization of n, I'm trying to write a program for this. (Project Euler)

Comment: Also to get the num. of factors in the first place, I would have to know the prime factorization.

Comment: Which number is it (Project Euler)?

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=735, but that’s not really relevant here.

Comment: There are straightforward algorithms for solving this *given a particular value of* $n$, of course.  But I don't see any direct solution in the general case, as it seems to depend crucially upon the prime factorization of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no general analytic solution, since it would seem to depend upon the prime factorization of $n$.

But the OP also asks for code.  That is very straightforward.  In *Mathematica*:

```
myfun[n_: Integer] := Length[
Select[Divisors[2 n^2], # <= n &]]
```

So:

```
myfun[9098345]
```

(* 27 *)

Here's a plot:

[image]

---

This isn't directly part of the problem, but seems to be the *motivation* of the problem.  If the above function is $f(n)$, calculate $F(N) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f(n)$, for $N = 10^{12}$.

I *think* the approach is the following:  Calculate the number of $2$s in that sum.  Then calculate the number of $3$s.  And so on, then add them up.

The number of $2$s is $10^{12}/2$.  The number of $3$s is $10^{12}/3$.  And so on.  But what is the maximum we add those up to in the total calculation?  I *think* it should be the largest factor allowed in the $10^{12}$ (last) term in the sum, i.e., $k_{max} = \sqrt{50} \cdot 10^5 = 707107$, obtained from the $2 n^2 = 10^{12}$ calculation.

If that's right, then:  $F(10^{12}) = 10^{12} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{k_{max}} \frac{1}{k} = 10^{12}\ {\rm HarmonicNumber}(k_{max}) = 10^{12} \cdot 14.0461536491411$.

There are probably some rounding artifacts that must be included, but I think this is the right approach.  Someone should do this with greater care.

Comment: Just curiosity (based on the project Euler problem), how much time does it take to calculate for $n=10^{12}$ ? (the problem actually asks the sum of divisors for $n=1$ to $10^{12}$... only 95 people have been able to answer so far!)

Comment: I do have one question: Exactly how efficient is this? (Time complexity wise) it looks like you’re just picking the divisors out that are <= n

Comment: The time to compute `myfun[10^(12)]` is $0.000721$ seconds on a Mac laptop.

Comment: Wow, is Mathematica really that fast? Thanks.

Comment: Factoring composites is not a hard computational problem, but yes... *Mathematica* is highly optimized for number theoretic functions.  I ran the first $10^6$ without smart re-use of calculations and it took $73$ seconds.  On a multiprocessor this highly parallel computation would be *much* faster.

Comment: Wow! You should be able to answer the problem within a reasonable time (sum of *yourfun* from $1$ to $10^{12}$), the calculation should be much faster for $10^{10}$ (for instance)

Comment: You want the *sum* of the `myfun`??

Comment: Not me, if you want to answer the [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=735)...

Comment: Even though I see no analytic simplification for a single $f(n)$ (i.e., `myfun`), the ProjectEuler task is a bit different.  It seeks $F(N) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f(n)$, with $N = 10^{12}$.  I think the trick here is to find out how many $2$s will appear in this big sum.  Then how many $3$s.  Then how many $4$s, and so on.  I don't have a solution approach beyond that, but I can see that there must be a simplification that doesn't require an analytic form for $f(n)$.

Comment: This is a tough one.  You can't assume that there are no factors in $(n, 2n)$.  For example, taking $n = 30, ~45$ is a factor of $1800$.

Comment: Huh?  But those factors do not enter the sum.

Comment: Hmm, but I don't see how you get that the number of 2s is $\frac{10^{12}}{2}$

Comment: I wrote out F(10): 1+2+3+3+3+5+3+4+5+5, but it does not follow your method

Comment: Ummm... $2$ is a factor or $2$, $4$, $6$, $8$, and $10$.  There are $10/2 = 5$ such factors.  So the number of factors of $2$ in $10^{12}$ is $10^{12}/2$.  Right?

Comment: Oh, yes, I think I misunderstood you, sorry. It is kind of like counting by 2's, right?

Comment: The approach for calculating the sum wouldn't work. The number of $4$s isn't given by $\frac{10^{12}}{4}$, but would instead be $\frac{10^{12}}{2}$, since $2(2n)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question. Assume $n=2^{a}(2k+1)$
for some integer $a$ and $k$. Let $f(x)=$numbers of positive divisors of the integer $x$ . Since factors of $2n^2\leq n$ we need number of factors of $2^{2a+1}(2k+1)^2$. Thus we have $f(2^a(2k+1))+c_{a}$.Where $c_{a}$ is the error factor has a small factor of bound, which needs to be deterministic. Although it's a rough idea, I am not finding the bound but for hints, you can try small cases. However
let $g(x)=$greatest integer lesser equal to x then, $$c_{a}\leq f(g(2^{\frac{2a+1}{2}}(2k+1)))-f(2^a(2k+1))$$.Where we know $f$ is famous divisor function or $\tau$ function and $g$ is the floor function.
Use this link for bound,
[Lower bound for the sum of divisor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811931/lower-bound-for-the-sum-of-divisor-function)

Comment: I don’t quite understand yet, but thank you very much for responding.

Comment: Actually, I am also thinking about the error term bound. I don't think that it would be zero for large enough a.

Comment: Yeah, this problem seems to have no fixed expression. As of now, I am trying to come up with an algorithm for it.

Comment: Yeah !!! Best of luck. Try hard.

Comment: I will, thank you